# Should a beginner learner start from Rails 3 or Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get into RoR and I just got the [Learning Rails 3](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021322.do) book but also version 4 of Rails is out, which I've been looking at it in [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). My question is: should I learn Rails 3 before jumping into 4? What's the difference between them?

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title.

Comment: Technology tools are often like children; the more radical they are when young, the more they stand out when they mature.  You can start with the latest version of anything, provided there is adequate documentation. However, often, one will find that the previous version (e.g., Rails 3, which has continued to be updated in parallel; Apache, Nginx, OSX, etc) is often more mature and more importantly, has much greater documentation and discussion on the web. This is the case with Capistrano; there is a ton of documentation for version 2, but very little for version 3.0+ (which has many issues)

Answer (score 2):

You can jump into rails 4 straight away. [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/) is a good place to start.